# various issues when setting up visualvm remote JVM connection with jstatd

Tags: visualvm, jvisualvm, jstatd

statd on remote machine may not be starting up correctly and visualvm user interface does not add connections.

On the remote machine, I created a policy file for jstatd:

```
grant codebase "file:/home/jonathan/jdk1.8.0_191/lib/tools.jar" {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I then execute jstatd: ./jstatd -p 1199 -J-Djava.security.policy=/home/jonathan/jstatd.policy

It seems to be running and there are no errors which I got when not specifying a port number or policy file.

In visualvm, I'm able to add the remote host but when I try to create a jstatd connection and fill the information, when clicking "ok", the popup just disappears. No errors, no connections under the node, no nothing. I enabled logging and there are no errors.

My questions:
1. Does jstatd REQUIRES an rmiregistry to work? Not specifying a port, will it attempt to connect to a default one (on port 1099)?
2. Running netstat doesn't show any binding on port 1199 which I've designated.
3. Why does visualvm not allow connections to be created?

Answer (score 0):

I think that [jstatd man page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstatd.html) should answer most of your questions. Regarding connection from visualvm - check VisualVM log file. Are there firewall(s) between visualvm and jstatd?